# How can I sum dynamic column's amounts?

Tags: php, mysql

Each animation can have one (an only one) theme linked, other themes can be created, also have no animation linked.
How can I sum the amounts of each theme at the bottom of this table ?
This displays 'Array' according to the number of amounts of a column.. 
(pardon my french)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            | Theme A  | Theme B  | Theme C  | Theme D  |  Theme n  | ...
Animation 1 |       5  |       -  |       -  |       -  |     ...
Animation 2 |       -  |       -  |       -  |       7  |     ...
Animation 3 |       6  |       -  |       -  |       -  |     ...
Animation 4 |       -  |       -  |       9  |       -  |     ...
Animation 5 |       -  |       -  |       -  |       1  |     ...
Animation n ...
       Sums:       11          0          9          8        ...
```

In the database, 'theme' is the id of the linked theme (from the 'themes' table), 'demiJournees' is the amount to sum.

```
CREATE TABLE `animations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dateAnim` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `theme` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   // One theme per animation
  `projet` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `partenaires` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `etablissement` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lieu` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `public` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `effectif` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `demiJournees` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   // The amount of the theme in an animation
  `matthias` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noellie` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `benevoles` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

**Model/AnimationManager.php**

```
public function sumTheme()
{
    $sql = "SELECT theme, SUM(demiJournees) FROM animations GROUP BY theme";
    $req = $this->db->query($sql);
    $sum = array();
    while ($ligne = $req->fetch())
    {
        $sum[] = new Animation($ligne);
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

**View/animation.php**

1st loop, display each theme's amount in the animation row (works):

```
foreach ($animations as $animation)
{
    foreach ($themes as $theme)
    {
        echo '<td id="' .    $theme->getId()  . '">';
        if ($animation->getTheme() == $theme->getId())
        {
            echo  $animation->getDemiJournees() . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '&nbsp;';
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
}
```

2nd loop: sum amounts in each theme's column (err: displays 'Array'):

```
foreach ($themes as $theme)
{
    echo '<td id="' . $theme->getId() . '">';
    foreach ($animations as $animation)
    {
        if ($animation->getTheme() == $theme->getId())
        {
            echo $animationManager->sumTheme();
        }            
      }
    echo '</td>';
}
```

Comment: You have to use `<tr></tr>` to create table rows. If you already have it, then please show the rest of your code and what result you are getting.

Comment: What is your question, and what is your problem ?

Comment: I think one of the issues you have here is that you're coupling together your php and view code too tightly. I would suggest instead of echoing out raw html in every function, simply pass data back to a template file.

Comment: You could use a sprinkling of javascript

Comment: Thank for you help. I think I will change the logic...

Answer (score -2):

Found it : Changed the 2nd loop with creating a variable to store the sum for each theme:

````
foreach ($themes as $theme) {
    echo '<td id="' . $theme->getId() . '">';

    // Initialise a variable for each theme
    $sumTheme = 0;
    foreach ($animations as $animation) {
        if ($animation->getTheme() == $theme->getId()) {
            // Ajoute la valeur à la variable du thème
            $sumTheme += $animation->getDemiJournees();
        }
    }
    // Display the total
    echo $sumTheme;
    echo '</td>';
}```
````

(moved answer inappropriately posted as edit to question)